# Undo hard drive partitioning

Tags: partitioning

Evening, I just deleted the virtualbox 6.1 from my system (Linux 20.04), I was hoping the partitioned hard drive would go back to its normal state after removing the virtualbox, now I don't have enough space on to configure the newly installed virt-manager (I had allocated about 32GB to the VM) how can I recover the "lost" storage space? please help...
(the disk partitioning is showing: part 1- 600MB & part 2: 61GB of 64GB)

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by `lost` storage space. Elaborate the question with a more descriptive background, and also add photo of your current disk partitions, using gparted or disks tool.

Comment: Do you have a Virtualbox directory in your /home ?

Comment: No, virtualbox has been completely deleted

Comment: x-special/nautilus-clipboard
copy
file:///home/butiza/Pictures/Screenshot%20from%202020-09-24%2001-01-02.png

Answer (score 0):

Your disk does not seem to be partitioned to 32+32. You probably configured VM to use an image file, not a dedicated partition. After you removed the VM itself, it's data (including 32Gb image) are still there. You can probably

```
sudo apt purge virtualbox
```

instead of

```
sudo apt remove virtualbox
```

this will probably remove the VM disk image. Or you can remove it manually, but I can't tell for sure where it is.

Comment: x-special/nautilus-clipboard
copy
file:///home/butiza/Pictures/Screenshot%20from%202020-09-24%2000-58-51.png

Comment: You are right, cause according to this screenshot I have 41GB free space.. (confused)